# How can I iterate an arrayList which is returned as part of result from Mongodb?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jsp, spring-mvc

This is my Model class in my Spring MVC Mongodb project

```
public class SampleProject{
  @Id
  String id;

  public String getId() {
  return id;
  }

  String regNo;
  String name;
  ArrayList<String> result;

  public String getRegNo() {
   return regNo;
  }

  public String getName() {
   return name;
  }

  public ArrayList<String> getResult() {
   return result;
  }
}
```

**This is how my Service class looks like**

```
@Repository("resultService")
public class ResultService {

@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "collectionName";

public StudentResult getStudentResult(String regNo) {
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("regNo").is(regNo));

StudentResult Ek = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, StudentResult.class);

return Ek;

}
}
```

**This is how my controller class looks like**

```
public class ResultController {

private final ResultService resultService;

@Autowired
public ResultController(ResultService resultService) {
this.resultService = resultService;
}

@RequestMapping(value ="/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getStudentResult(String regNo, ModelMap model){
model.addAttribute("studentResult",resultService.getStudentResult(regNo));

return "output";
}
}
```

**This is how my jsp looks like**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="Oracle Technology Network for Java Developers" %>


 <c:out value="${studentResult.name}"/>
  <c:out value="${studentResult.regNo}"/>
    <c:out value="${studentResult.deptName}"/>
      <c:out value="${studentResult.collName}"/>
        <c:out value="${studentResult.result}"/> <!--This line prints the arraylist as arraylist.--> 

<!--But the following iteration using foreach doesn't work -->
<c:forEach var="student" items="${studentResult}"> 
            <tr>
                <td>${student.name}</td>
                <td>${student.regNo}</td>
                <td><input type="button" value="delete" onclick="window.location='person/delete?id=${person.id}'"/></td>
            </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

This is what the **db** looks

> { "_id" : ObjectId("53f017f2300469e091855f0d"), "regNo" : "3103",
>   "name" : "ABCD", "collName" : " INSTITUTE OF ENGINEERING AND
>   TECHNOLOGY", "deptName" : "B.Tech Technology", "result" : [ {
>   "subjCode" : "CY6251", "grade" : "E", "result" : "PASS", "subjName" :
>   "Engineering Chemistry – II" }, { "subjCode" : "GE6151", "grade" :
>   "E", "result" : "PASS", "subjName" : "Computer Programming" }, {
>   "subjCode" : "GE6252", "grade" : "D", "result" : "PASS", "subjName" :
>   "Basic Electrical and Electronics Engineering" }, { "subjCode" :
>   "GE6253", "grade" : "E", "result" : "PASS", "subjName" : "Engineering
>   Mechanics" }, ] }

Now how can I iterate the arraylist in JSP so that I display each subject Name and grade from the arraylist.

I changed my taglib declaration as said. But before changing it as he said as well as after changing it, my jsp shows "Unknown tag 
 (c:forEach)." which I couldn't resolve as per most of answers in Stackoverflow.

Comment: I think you have wrong uri in taglib. what is "Oracle Technology Network for Java Developers"?  instead use this <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

Comment: I get the following error "Can not find the tag library descriptor for "java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/
 core"  "

Comment: did you have include jstl library? or did you map it in web.xml. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info for more info.

Comment: @user3705478 hi did you resolve the problem?

Comment: @SanKrish Nope. I couldn't resolve it. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried
"<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>" instead of
"<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>"
??

Comment: @user3705478 Have you tried the Krishnalal comment ? Does that help

Comment: Yes. Still it doesn't work. I downloaded the jstl 1.2 jar and put in target/WEB-INF/lib folder. Still I don't see the error going away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my result ArrayList was not of type String. It is of type Result where I have subjCode, subjName as String. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the whole object inside the foreach instead of the ArrayList you actually want to iterate on.  You're only putting one StudentResult into the model, but StudentResult.results is the arrayList.

(That's assuming that you want to iterate on StudentResult.results)

If not, try adding Arrays.asList(resultService.getStudentResult(regNo)) to your model instead, and your foreach should work, but only print one result.

Also,
the taglib is incorrect as user23123412 mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I want to iterate StudentResult.results, but I don't want to change my model since I won't be able to get collName and deptName.

Answer (score 0):

Its not even necessary to download the jars . the `uri` is enough. try adding `<% @page isElIgonred="false" %>`.

I guess it is the problem with `EL` as the line above the `c:forEach` works. Try using it completely with `jstl`

```
<c:forEach var="student" items="${studentResult}"> 
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value='${student.name}' /></td>
                <td><c:out value='${student.regNo}'</td>
                <td><input type="button" value="delete" onclick="window.location='person/delete?id=<c:out value='${person.id}'/>'"/></td>
            </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: 1) May I know What you mean by "Try using it completely with jstl"?
2) Your piece of code just looks same as in the question

Comment: I have added `c:out` tags .. if you have ignored EL your code wont work . so asked you to try with jstl

Comment: 1) It was difficult to make out the difference, Thanks. 2) So to use completly with JSTL, following line would be sufficient,  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>  right?

Comment: I am able to see name and regNo, but I don't know how to iterate result to see subjCode, subjName, grade and result.

Comment: @user3705478 couldnt find any getters setters for the subjCode, subjName, grade and result